# What is the use of anonymous functions in javascript?What's wrong in defining a function with a name each and everytime?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Both the functions below give the same output,right?So what are the uses of using an anonymous function, instead of using a properly named function such as the second one below

```
function foo () {
   // some work done 
}
foo();

let foo = function () {
    // some work done 
}
foo();
```

Comment: What if you want to pass a (callback) function to another function? Do you want to always define a named function for that?

Comment: In your example, the *first* one is the properly declared function, the second one is the "anonymous" function expression.

Comment: The uses of anonymous functions are when you do something else with it (e.g. passing it as an argument) than to initialise a variable with it